# Will MediaPlayer continue to play in paused Android activity?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Within an Android Activity, I am using the following solution to create a MediaPlayer with seemless looping:

```
MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mResId);
MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mResId);

mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mResId);
                mp1.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mp2.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);

            }
        });

mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mResId);
                mp2.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
            }
        });

mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
mp1.start();
```

If the user is using another application or locks the screen, should the application remain alive with sound playing indefinitely? Is it advised to use a foreground service, or will the act of constantly creating new MediaPlayers suffice to keep the app alive and playing sound?

Comment: You have to run mediaplayer as an audioservice. [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030) is a good tutorial how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play music if user moves to other app or locks the screen, use a foreground service and make sure to display a notification to user while the service is in foreground.

It is not advisable to use different MediaPlayer objects to play music in loop.
I suggest you to use ExoPlayer to achieve the above functionalities.

You can use the below code to loop the music:

```
exoPlayer!!.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
```

Watch this tutorial : [Building feature-rich media apps with ExoPlayer (Google I/O '18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8&t=1516s) provided by Android Developers team at Google.